# Jquery validate validación digit mensaje personalizado erróneo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

Tengo un código con jquery y jquery validation donde al aplicar la validación sobre un input con distintas validaciones quiero personalizar los distintos mensajes de error pero al encontrar un error de digito inválido el mismo coloca el del valor mínimo. Alguno sabe a que puede deberse?, entra en conflicto las distintas validaciones?, es la versión que uso?, es el type text el problema?

Les dejo una muestra funcional y resumida de mi caso. Para reproducir ingresar letras y verán que la leyenda de error es la del valor mínimo y no la de digit.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myForm").validate({});
  $("#myField").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    maxlength: 6,
    min: 1,
    digits: true,
    messages: {
      digits: "error digito",
      required: "error requerido",
      maxlength: "error tamaño maximo",
      min: "error valor minimo"
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js?"></script>

  <form id="myForm" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input id="myField" name="myField" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="ddd" dynamicParam="myField">
  </form>
</body>
```

Esta es solo una muestra que tiene el mismo efecto que mi caso, aunque en la versión final en la que trabajo no es específicamente esta forma.

Desde ya se agradece cualquier ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Después de investigar un poco más *aparentemente* y no es el motivo confirmado. Pareciera que la evaluación de las distintas validaciones no es por atributo sino secuencial. Por lo que al poner primero **digits** que min. El ejemplo funciona correctamente.